# Python: How may I coerce a row of a pandas dataframe a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
type(df_s1)
Out[362]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

This is one rows of it. It is a series, not a dataframe. But I want it to be a dataframe. How may I do it?

```
type(df_s1.iloc[(j+2), 0:n_s])
Out[363]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

It's not a problem for more than one rows in the dataframe.

```
type(df_s1.iloc[(j-1):(j+2), 0:n_s])

Out[364]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Series.to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) method to convert a series into the dataframe.

Use:

```
sf = df_s1.iloc[(j+2), 0:n_s].to_frame()
print(type(sf))
```

This prints:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```